# How do I make an element appear with JavaScript without overriding style?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to display a div that was previously hidden:

```
document.getElementById('theDiv').style.display = 'block';
```

The problem is that when I execute this, the div loses all prior CSS formatting. Is there a way that I can have this same functionality while keeping my CSS formatting?

Comment: It's really not possible for that to happen.

Comment: Very sorry...just tested something and realized that something else is the problem... upvoting all the answers that indicated that. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `style.display` to `block` has no effect on other CSS formatting.  The only one exception I can think of is if the item was previously `display:inline`, then setting it to `display:block` would change the layout.  But, all other CSS items will be unaffected.

If this is not what you are observing, then you may not be telling us the whole story here and something else that you aren't showing us with your code must be going on.  If that's the case, then please try to reduce your test case to a small example in jsFiddle so we can see the actual code that causes the problem.

Comment: Why a downvote?  This turns out to be exactly what was really going on.  Something else (other than the code the OP disclosed) was causing the problem.